# titlesec & fancyhdr - the chapter name doesn't get printed at the header

Tags: chapters, fancyhdr, titlesec

In a document using the titlsec & fancyhdr packages, I couldn't manage to print the chapter name at the header center.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,openany,14pt,]{extbook}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\filleft\bfseries\Large}
  {\Huge\thechapter}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{3pt}\titlerule\vspace{0ex}\filright}
  [\vspace{0ex}]

\usepackage[left=2.34cm, right=2.34cm, top=2.66cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[twoside]{fancyhdr} 

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{#1}{}}
 
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
  \fancyhead[C]{\leftmark} % rightmark,leftmark thechapter don't work
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Introduction}
Alright, here we are...

\pagebreak

Alright, one mone page...
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to print the chapter name, i.e. *Introduction* ?

Comment: `\chapter*` doesn't issue `\chaptermark`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. If I don't use `\chapter*` the `titlesec` title gets messed up (because of the chapter number being added or something else)

Comment: You can manually add \chaptermark{Introduction).

Comment: @JohnKormylo Adding `\chaptermark{Introduction)` partially solved the problem.  Leaving `\fancyhead[C]{\leftmark}` intact, **Chapter 0: Introduction**  appeared in header. In order to get rid of "Chapter 0:" I've tried `\rightmark` `\thechaptername` etc, didn't work it out. How to print solely the chapter *name* i.e. the *Introduction* ? Thanks.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Nope, AFAIK nothing was redefining the `\chaptermark`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code used the `explicit` parameter of `titlesec` to be able to use the format settings for `\chapter` to add the necessary `leftmark`, using the chapter title.

The standard first page of a chapter uses a `plain` format, the following ones the `fancy` format.

[image: x]

```
\documentclass[a5paper,openany,14pt,]{extbook}

\usepackage[left=2.34cm, right=2.34cm, top=2.66cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}% changed <<<<

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang] % changed numbered chapters
{\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{3pt}\titlerule\bfseries\Large\filleft}
{\Huge\thechapter}
{1ex}
{#1\filright \markboth{#1}{}} % add the leftmark <<<

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 

\fancypagestyle{plain}{% used in the chapter first page
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[C]{} % OPTIONAL \leftmark works here <<<<
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[C]{\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

    \chapter*{Introduction 0}
    Alright, here we are...
    
    \pagebreak
    
    Alright, one more page...
    
    \chapter{Introduction I}
    Alright, here we are...
    
    \pagebreak
    
    Alright, one more page...
\end{document}
```

**OPTION** The next example adds the chapter number to the header in the case of numbered chapters.

To this end, two title formats were defined: the first for numbered chapters and the second for unnumbered chapters.

[image: z]

```
\documentclass[a5paper,openany,14pt,]{extbook}

\usepackage[left=2.34cm, right=2.34cm, top=2.66cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}% changed <<<<

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang] % changed numbered chapters
{\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{3pt}\titlerule\bfseries\Large\filleft}
{\Huge\thechapter}
{1ex}
{#1\filright \markboth{\thechapter\enspace#1}{}} % add the leftmark with the chapter number included<<<

\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[hang]% added  unnumbered chapters <<<<<<<<<
{\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{3pt}\titlerule\bfseries\Large\filleft}
{}
{1ex}
{#1\filright\markboth{#1}{}} % add the leftmark using the chapter title

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 

\fancypagestyle{plain}{% used in the chapter first page
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[C]{} % OPTIONAL \leftmark works here <<<<
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[C]{\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

    \chapter*{Introduction 0}
    Alright, here we are...
    
    \pagebreak
    
    Alright, one more page...
    
    \chapter{Introduction I}
    Alright, here we are...
    
    \pagebreak
    
    Alright, one more page...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,openany,14pt,]{extbook}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\filleft\bfseries\Large}
  {\Huge\thechapter}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{3pt}\titlerule\vspace{0ex}\filright}
  [\vspace{0ex}]

\usepackage[left=2.34cm, right=2.34cm, top=2.66cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[twoside]{fancyhdr} 

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{#1}{}}
 
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyhead{}
  \fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
  \fancyhead[C]{\leftmark} % rightmark,leftmark thechapter don't work
  \fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Introduction}
\chaptermark{Introduction}
Alright, here we are...

\pagebreak

Alright, one mone page...
\end{document}
```