# How to expand the title text on the chapter title fully and on the header partially?

Tags: fancyhdr, titlesec, soul

Having benefited from this [TeX.SE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/676633/244554) I've written this code:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,openany,14pt,]{extbook}

\usepackage[left=2.34cm, right=2.34cm, top=2.66cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{3pt}\titlerule\bfseries\Large\filleft}
{\Huge\thechapter}
{1ex}
{#1\filright \markboth{#1}{}} % add the leftmark <<<

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyhead[RO]{\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont\thepage}
  \fancyhead[C]{\leftmark} 
\fancyhead[LE]{\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont\thepage}
}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter{}:
#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection{} #1}{}}
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage{soul} % package to stretch the chapter name horizontally

\begin{document}

\sodef\spaceout{}{0pt plus 1fil}{.4em plus 1fil}{0pt}
\chapter*{\makebox[\linewidth][l]{\spaceout{INTRODUCTION}}}% \chaptermark{Introduction}%
% If I add \chaptermark{Introduction  then "Chapter 0: Introduction" appears which is not desired.
 
    Alright, here we are...
    
    \pagebreak
    
    Alright, one more page...
    
    \chapter*{\makebox[\linewidth][l]{\spaceout{HERE WE GO NOW}}}
    Alright, here we are...
    
    \pagebreak
    
    Alright, one more page...
\end{document}
```

to get the kind of layout given in the right screenshot:

[image]

How to do it?

Comment: you should never have markup in the title.  `\chapter*{\makebox[\linewidth][l]{\spaceout{HERE WE GO NOW}}}` will cause the problems you show. Just use `\chapter*{Introduction}` . Any letterspacing, uppercasing etc can be applied in the definition of the layout of the chapter and page heads, and table of contents, all of which will require different handling

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Actually, I was feeling something was wrong as I used that markup in the title but I don't know enough TeX to make it appropriate.

Comment: In some disciplines it's fairly common to have inline mathematics in a title, which results in things like a font change. I regard it as a bad practice but it's still fairly common. \spaceout seems like a stretch for what should be tolerated.

Comment: @mccurley Thanks for commenting. TeX markup manipulation i.e. extracting the text out of it is not necessary really. I've greatly simplified the question. See the edited version. It doesn't get any simpler I think.

Comment: Consider the possibility of using `\newif\ifInHeader`. Re-define the header (in fancyhdr syntax) so that the boolean is only true locally there. Then define how the title is spaced, so that it produces different results depending on `\ifInHeader`. I have tried something similar to prevent placing an image in headers (patching `\includegraphics` so that it is sensitive to the boolean). It works. But my document class and entire structure is too different from yours, to post code.

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't use markup in the argument to `\chapter`: manage the typesetting in the argument to `\titleformat` and in the headers.

I'd not redefine the `plain` style, because it's used in the chapter start pages.

You're missing to set `headheight`.

Instead of `soul`, I believe it's better to use `microtype`.

Finally, 14pt font size on a5paper? Are you sure?

```
\documentclass[a5paper,openany,14pt,]{extbook}

\usepackage[
  left=2.34cm,
  right=2.34cm,
  top=2.66cm,
  headheight=17pt,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{3pt}\titlerule\bfseries\Large\filleft}
  {\Huge\thechapter}
  {1ex}
  {\filright\spaceoutchaptertitle} % add the leftmark <<<

\newcommand{\spaceoutchaptertitle}[1]{\textls{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

\fancypagestyle{thesis}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyhead[RO]{\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont\thepage}%
  \fancyhead[C]{\textls{\MakeUppercase{\leftmark}}}%
  \fancyhead[LE]{\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont\thepage}%
}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter{}: #1}{}%
}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\pagestyle{thesis}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Introduction}
\markboth{Introduction}{Introduction}
 
    Alright, here we are...
    
    \pagebreak
    
    Alright, one more page...
    
    \chapter{Here we go now}
    Alright, here we are...
    
    \pagebreak
    
    Alright, one more page...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The `INTRODUCTION` must appear roughly the same length as those 2 bars above it. In this solution it is contracted which makes it appear way shorter than those 2 bars. Furthermore I'd like to be able to readjust the space out for the header titles so I think I should stick to the `soul` package because it handles that fine detail quite good. Yep, 14pt font size on a5paper because I'm mimicking an old style book.

Comment: @LarsMalmsteen Also the letterspacing with `\textls` is customizable.